# Grails svg image href referring the png is not showing

Tags: grails

This is difficult to explain. I needed some fills in Coreldraw that I liked and saved as `SVG`. When Coreldraw saved my svg, I got one folder called `soil_Images` with `soil_ImgID1.png` inside and `soil.svg`. And I put inside of `web-app/images` project. For some reason, the image png is not shown.

I have my svg like in my gsp:

```
<image x="177" y="76" width="36" height="23" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/projectName/images/soil.svg"></image>
```

And my `soil.svg` has another image tag that shows true image that I want:

```
 <image x="44" y="29" width="8156" height="11707" xlink:href="soil_Images/soil_ImgID1.png"/>
```

I tried to add a contextpath like: `${application.contextPath}/images/soil_Images/soil_ImgID1.png`.
 That didn't work. What am I missing?

- In chrome resources, the image hasn't been downloaded.

Comment: Do you get 404 error? What happens when you try to type the image path in browser's address bar?

Comment: Can you please try using below code
<img src="${resource(dir:'images/soil_Images',file:'soil_ImgID1.png')}">

Comment: @Aramiti I don't see any 404 error or similar error request. And If type : `/myProjectName/images/soil_Images/soil_ImgID1.png` load the image.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar Tried and didn't work, didn't show any error and the resources from chrome didn't download too.

Comment: Can you try accessing the url that is generated in src attribute?

Comment: yes, I can access. I can even see the png shown at : `/projectName/images/soil_Images/soil_ImgID1.png` on my svg.

Comment: Can you try using
`<object id="svg1" data="/projectName/images/soil_Images/soil.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`

Comment: For the sake of testing, try an image that actually work, by hardcoding the image path to "src"' attribute. If you still have issues displaying the image, you might have URL mapping rules setup that prevents you from displaying the image. Just out of curiosity, you don't happen to have "ImagesController", do you?

Comment: @Aramiti As you said, I hardcoded and didn't work. And I don't have ImagesController. Its hardcoded.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar The image appears not found and chrome didn't give me any error requests.

Comment: I highly suspect, you either have permission issues or your path is incorrect.

Comment: @Aramiti the path is correct, if I go to the path, the image load. And about permission, if I can access, its mean It has permission, right?

Comment: If you can access it through URL path (not file path) in you browser then yes, you don't have any permission issues. The image URL that renders properly in your browser should do the same in your grails GSP. Try simple HTML img tag with the same path and see if the image renders.

Comment: @Aramiti I can see the image if I load him at localhost:8080/projectName/images/soil_Images/soil_ImgID1.png.

Comment: If the above URL worked then this should also work:`${request.contextPath}/images/soil_Images/soil_ImgID1.png

Answer (score 0):

Building off of [Matt Busche's blog post](http://matthewbusche.com/blog2/2015/01/05/using-grails-assets-when-you-cant-use-the-asset-tag/) on using the asset pipeline with SVG and PNG fallback images, try pointing to the asset pipeline location instead of hardcoding. Note the `assetPath` with `src` (the relative path you are using if not the default asset pipeline image location) and the name of the image.

```
<image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="${assetPath(src: 'imgs/' + logoSVG)}" src="${assetPath(src: 'imgs/' + logoPNG)}"></image>
```

Comment: you mean to put it on soil.svg or inside of gsp page contains svg?

Comment: Inside the gsp page itself.